# Unable to set the query string value to dynamic anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where I am trying to set the Id to the url by looping and framing the anchor tag but couldn't I am missing something but I couldn't figure it out

```
    $.each(model.data, function () {
        var customer = this;
        var event = customer.Event;
        var aTag = '<a href="/Controller/Detail/?Id="' + customer.EventId+ ' class="ReportableEve text-primary" title="Details">' + event + "</a>";
        $("td", row).eq(0).html(aTag);
        $("td", row).eq(1).html(customer.VesselName);
        $("td", row).eq(2).html(customer.VesselType);
        $("td", row).eq(3).html(customer.EventType);
        $("td", row).eq(4).html(customer.EventDate);
        $("td", row).eq(5).html(customer.Severity);
        $("td", row).eq(6).html(customer.Status);
        $("td", row).eq(7).html(customer.Assignee);
        $("td", row).eq(8).html(customer.BriefDescription);
        $("#ReportableEventGrid").append(row);
        row = $("#ReportableEventGrid tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
    });
```

when I inspect the element this is what I see

```
 <a href="/Controller/Detail/?Id=" "1="" class="ReportableEve text-primary" title="Details">1 26/10/2021</a>
```

I need this to be as

```
 <a href="/Controller/Detail/?Id=1" class="ReportableEve text-primary" title="Details">1 26/10/2021</a>
```

Comment: Template literals usually helps root out these pesky append typos. `var aTag = ´<a href="/Controller/Detail/?Id=${customer.EventId}" class="ReportableEve text-primary" title="Details">${event}</a>´;`

Comment: Please note I used the wrong "tick" in my example of the template literal above, because it's usually reserved for code highlighting on Stack Overflow. Use the backtick to define a template literal ( ` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but it looks like a syntax error when you generate the anchor tag.

`var aTag = '<a href="/Controller/Detail/?Id="' + customer.EventId+ ' class="ReportableEve text-primary" title="Details">' + event + "</a>";`

In your syntax, the `href` attribute is already closed before appending the `id` query string. Update your code as follows:

`var aTag = '<a href="/Controller/Detail/?Id=' + customer.EventId+ '" class="ReportableEve text-primary" title="Details">' + event + '</a>';`